# get original file name and extension for TemporaryUploadedFile for django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i am uploading file from react form to django rest framework.In django, i am using following code to get uploaded files array.

```
images_data =dict((self.context['request'].data).lists()).get('images', None)
```

in settings.py file, i am using TemporaryFileUploadHandler

```
 FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
```

i want to know the original name of the file that was sent to server. in name i just get a random string with no extension. i want to save the file with original extension and name.
how can i get the original name and extension of the file?
i am using python 3.7.12